# storage/emulated/0/ open faild:ENOENT (no such file or directory)?

Tags: java, android, file

i have below code that work in some phone and dont work in some other phone.

my code is for saving an image.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
path += "/";
File fff=new File(path + "/xalopex/Mobile/");
if (!fff.exists())
    fff.mkdirs();



path += "xalopex/Mobile/";
path += "lg";

    File filename;
    try {
       filename = new File(path + ".jpg");
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
       MyImageBitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();                         
       out.close();
       MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                                filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(),
                                        filename.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
                        //this part will run
                        // e is storage/emulated/0/xalopex/Mobile/lg.jpg open faild:ENOENT (no such file or directory)

    }
```

where i am wrong ?
How i can fix it?

Comment: directory is getting created or even directory is also not getting created

Comment: @praveen I have folder in sdcard.so created

Comment: try to observe Logcat are you getting any exceptions etc.then you may be able o solve problem or else post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess and say its because you need to be accessing /storage/emulated/legacy instead of /storage/emulated/0

I could be wrong.. but I see there are no accepted answers so I'll give this a try :)